# How to watch video streaming from home PC with full control, like on a local player?

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming, video-streaming, remote-control

I'd like to watch (and listen to) all my media on home PC, from a netbook elsewhere. And I'd like it to appear as seamless as possible, as if I were playing media locally, but actually streaming from home.

I've tried using VLC streaming wizard and it doesn't work every time for me. Sometimes I have to retry streaming with different settings. And I only figured out how to add selected media files to the stream playlist, which isn't very convenient. In the best case I can currently open the stream, but I don't know how to control it aside from TeamViewer and similar programs. Ideally, I'd like to be able to use my player's controls to control VLC at home (play/pause, position, next/prev, etc).

VLC also appears to have a remote control feature, but I haven't explored it much yet. So far it looks like a good choice of streaming app, aside from file selection.

How can I select any media using folder tree view to stream from home player, and control playback from another computer?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at Plex Server.   https://plex.tv/

Works well with Linux, Mac and Windows.   Allows you to stream any content you add to it to a browser, as well as apps for Android and iPhone.   The only thing it does not have is a playlist feature to queue up multiple episodes of whatever you are watching.

Comment: Is it free or paid?

Comment: I think the PC/Windows server is free, but you have to pay for the app for iPhone/Android.